# Why does spring container create beans even for the class with default access without checking the access restrictions?

Tags: spring, access-modifiers

I have a package "A" with interface "Shape" and implementing class "Rectangle". Both the interface and class have default access. Now I have another package "B" with class "ShapeTester". In this ShapeTester class,  I try to instantiate class Rectangle or try to declare a variable of type Shape and I get the compilation error which is expected. 
But in the ShapeTester class, if I use the Spring container to create the bean, it creates the bean for class Rectangle.

Is it not wrong of Spring Framework to create the beans without even checking that the class where the bean is being created for Rectangle doesn't even know that any such Rectangle class even exists?

Answer (score 0):

Spring just create the object instances. It does not matter from which class or package you start the spring container.

The java concept of visibility is more related to the static relationship. For example if you have a class A in package a, then all rules are based on this. It does not matter if class A is instantiated by an Class B from an other package.